# How do I stop unknown ads’ popup in my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website. Its running well from a long time. But suddenly some unknown ads popup in my website.When i enter my website from google search, popup ads occurs in my website. but ads dont occur when i directly view the website from browser.I have checked the website with malware checker..nothing found. I also have access to the dashboard. How can I stop the ads popup from my wordpress website..how can remove the ad popup permanently ?

Please help

Comment: Sounds like malware, despite what the checker says. The code to do this is coming from somewhere, and if you didn’t make changes recently then something has got infected to make it happen. As you have no idea where this could be, the only thing to do is roll back to your last clean backup. And do it **quickly** before Google penalises your site!

Comment: i have to solve the problem and how can i stop malware @Fluffykitten..is there any plugin or custom code available ?

Comment: You can roll back to your last clean backup. (You do make backups, don’t you?). That really is your only option when you don’t know where the malware is. Even if you *did* know what plugin/vulnerability introduced it, it’s still almost impossible to clean and even then rolling back is the only safe option.

Comment: what guarantee that the backup will not effected again.?.this why i need a solution like any plugin or custom code to add for stopping malware injection @Fluffykitten

Comment: There *is* no safe solution other than your last clean backup. You will need to check back through your backups one by one to find the last one without the malware. Malware can get everywhere in your code, database, your there files, other plugins, etc. So it is virtually impossible to clean. If you still want to try to do this, that is a much more complex question that is way beyond the terms of Stack Overflow and will require very specific knowledge. You’ll need to go to google to do more in-depth research on this.